# How to hide and show MainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt, show-hide

I am creating an application that has two MainWindow.
After clicking on the button, the second MainWindow is displayed. But if in the code of the first button I give `hide()` MainWindow1, I can't send it again.

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    hide();
    two = new MainWindow2 (this);
    two -> show();

}



#include "mainwindow2.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow2.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow2::MainWindow2(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow2)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow2::~MainWindow2()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow2::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
}
```

Comment: `MainWindow w;   w.show();` note that `w` here is a local  variable and its lifetime ends at the end of the scope which means when `on_pushButton_clicked()` finishes `w` no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code...

```
void MainWindow2::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
}
```

The `MainWindow` instance `w` is local to the function and will be destroyed as soon as it goes out of scope.

Your intent is (to me at least) slightly unlcear, but my guess is that you want `MainWindow2::on_pushButton_clicked` to re-show the original `MainWindow`.  If so, then you can simply do...

```
void MainWindow2::on_pushButton_clicked ()
{
    if (auto *w = parentWidget())
        w->show();
}
```

since the current `MainWindow2` instance was created with the original `MainWindow` as its parent.